# Macro for identical IF statement across multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an simple if statement that I want to use to concatenate the results from multiple (25+) worksheets into one cell on a master worksheet.

If statement is

```
=IF('400'!C23="y",'400'!$C$2,"")
```

My current method is to bash multiple IF statements together into a really long string (see below) but I'd rather make a function (say, ifconcat() )that I can call up that uses a table list of my tab names to go through each worksheet. Can anyone help me with this?

```
IF('400'!C23="y",", "&'400'!$C$2,"")&IF('410'!C23="y",", "&'410'!$C$2,"")&IF('420'!C23="y",", "&'420'!$C$2,"")
```

will currently return values in C2 from sheets 400, 410 and 420.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following UDF. It fetches and concatenates values from many worksheets where `matchVal` parameter is matched. `matchCel` is the cell to compare and `getCel` is the cell to concatenate if the match succeeds. The parameter `sheetNames` is an optional list of worksheets to lookup; If this parameter is missing, the values are fetched from all worksheets except the caller worksheet.

```
Function FetchSheets(matchVal, matchCel As Range, getCel As Range, ParamArray sheetNames()) As String
    Dim sheetCol As New Collection, sh
    If UBound(sheetNames) < 0 Then
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Not sh Is Application.Caller.Parent Then sheetCol.Add sh
        Next
    Else
        For Each sh In sheetNames
            sheetCol.Add Worksheets(sh)
        Next
    End If

    For Each sh In sheetCol
        If sh.Range(matchCel.address).Value2 = matchVal Then
            If Len(FetchSheets) > 0 Then FetchSheets = FetchSheets & ", "
            FetchSheets = FetchSheets & sh.Range(getCel.address).Value2
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

To apply it to your example, you can replace your formula with this:

```
=FetchSheets("y", C23, $C$2, "400", "410", "420")
```

If you want to fetch from all the sheets except the master, enter this in some master cell:

```
=FetchSheets("y", C23, $C$2)
```

Comment: That's awesome! Works perfectly :) Thanks very much!